# Deselecting original feature from selection of both original and duplicate features?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, duplication, attribute-assistant

I have a field which is supposed to hold a unique identifier, however due to issues with Attribute Assistant I have multiple features which have the same unique ID. I want to write a script which will select duplicates and remove the originals from the selection. The duplicated field is FID, the originals will have a lower OID (also, there can be more than one duplicate).

I have used SelectLayersByAttribute_management to select features where there are more than one feature with the same FID:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("MyLayer", "NEW_SELECTION", "FID In (SELECT FID FROM MyFeatureClass GROUP BY FID HAVING Count(*)>1))
```

This selects both originals and duplicates, but how do I now remove the features which have the original FID value?

The originals will have a lower OID value:

```
OID   FID
 1    x101    ORIGINAL
 2    x101    DUPLICATE
 3    x102    ORIGINAL
 4    x102    DUPLICATE
 5    x102    DUPLICATE
```

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.1

Comment: Does the solution have to be a script?  What you're trying to do can be accomplished with a summarize, then join, then select by attributes, then switch selection.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid so. I can fix the problem manually pretty easily but I'm trying to automate the process. This is just a small section of what will be a larger script, it's just what I'm currently stuck on.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?  Also I have removed your "PS" about Attribute Assistant.  If you have a another question, please ask it separately.

Comment: @user3596332: Which reply matched what you were looking for? Please accept the passing answer ; else maybe comment further.

Comment: @Hélène Hi, I'm awaiting a further comment from Midavalo who has been very helpful so far.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should loop through the features in your layer using a Search Cursor, and keep track of when a value already exists, adding subsequent feature OIDs to a list to select.

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("MyLayer")
selOID = list()
existingValue = list()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['OID@', 'FID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] in existingValue:
            selOID.append(row[0])
        else:
            existingValue.append(row[1])

lyr.setSelectionSet('NEW', selOID)
```

For more info on `lyr.setSelectionSet()` see the [`setSelectionSet()` method for the Layer class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#M2_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878)

---

As the `setSelectionSet()` isn't available until 10.3, you can use this method to select the list of ObjectIDs.  Replace the last line in the code sample above with the last two lines below (the rest is the same code)

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("MyLayer")
selOID = list()
existingValue = list()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['OID@', 'FID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] in existingValue:
            selOID.append(row[0])
        else:
            existingValue.append(row[1])

query = 'OBJECTID IN (' + ','.join(map(str, selOID)) + ')' 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

Comment: Small caveat: `setSelectionSet()` doesn't seem to be available prior to 10.3.

Comment: @RichardMorgan You may be right - a quick look in the 10.2 docs didn't find it.  I have requested the OP tell us the version.  The mention of Attribute Assistant makes me think it's not too old, although the AA does still work on a minimum release of 10.2.1, so if that is the case my answer may not work

Comment: 10.2.1 it is I'm afraid

Comment: @user3596332 I have updated my answer to include an option that should work pre 10.3

Comment: @Midavalo This is so close but not quite there. It returns the correct number of records however I need it to specifically avoid the record with the lowest OID. I think this excludes the first record it comes across but that may not necessarily be the one with the lowest OID. Thank you for getting it this far.

Comment: @user3596332 It might be possible to add a sort into the cursor - something like `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['OID@', 'FID'], sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY OBJECTID'))`.  I'll have a proper play in a couple of hours when I can get on my computer to test.  If that doesn't work, we can always do some sorting with lists etc. in the python to ensure you get the lowest OBJECTID.

Comment: @Midavalo Did you have any luck with adding a sort into the cursor? Thanks for the time you're putting into this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd explore [Delete Identical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm)  (Data Management Toolbox), which removes all but one of the identical records found. As a ArcToolbox tool, you can use it in scripts, or directly from the GUI.

To list the duplicates without deleting them, the [Find Identical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/find-identical.htm) tool is also available, using the "Output only duplicated records" parameter. However, this outputs a new table, rather than creating a selection in your original data.

Comment: I don't want to delete either of the records. I just want to deselect the original so that I can update the others' attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This Select By Attribute, Where Clause seems to work, only selecting the DUPLICATE rows when the same FID has ORIGINAL also.

```
Status = 'DUPLICATE' and Fid in (SELECT FID FROM dups where Status = 'ORIGINAL') and  Fid in (SELECT FID FROM dups where Status = 'DUPLICATE')
```